# Backup Structured Data and Unstructured Data seperately in SQL Server - Is it Possible?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, backup, availability-groups, filestream

Can I get some inputs on below:

SQL Server Version : 2014 SP2 GDR with AOAG environment.

Is it possible to backup Structured Data & Unstructured Data (FileStream) separately in SQL Server ?

For structured data backup, I am reading about the partial backup to exclude FILESTREAM file groups.

If backup Structured Data & Unstructured Data (FileStream) separately in SQL Server is possible , can I restore Structured Data & Unstructured Data (FileStream) separately ? How to restore FileStream data alone ? or structured data alone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such direct feature. You would work at the filegroup level, and at that level SQL Server doesn't care whether it is a filestream or something else you have in that filegroup.

And when you restore a part of the database, you need to have the primary file group (since this contains all metadata) and whatever other filegroups you want. The non-restored filegroups will be "defunct", and will forever have those "ghost" filegroups hanging around (there's no way to delete/remove a defunct filegroup).

Comment: Thanks @Tibor , can you please help me understand below case .           If I ask the question in a different way, can we have a the dB created empty and just restore the structure file group? 
Does this dB run?

Comment: Yes, you can exclude the filestream filegroup, but you will forever have this weird non-functional filegroup hanging around. If you don't want to have the filestream data in your backups, one can question why use filestream in the first place? Why not just have the file name in the table. (Of course, I don't know anything about your bigger picture, so I'm just talking out loud here...)